# how to make a view appear only if is the first time?

Tags: ios, view, storyboard

Thanks in advance .

I wanna make a view appear only if the application is launch for the first time, I have work with a similar code to display Alerts, but I can find a way to make it with a Storyboard view ? For example my idea is : in the image below I have 7 buttons so I want the user to select which Country/Button they wanna use after this first time launch (it will be a button where they can change it back ) and how can I save the value of the button (the one that the user choose) so that every time the app launches again it goes straight to the one they selected when the app was installed ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

There are two pretty easy solutions I can think of.

First, in both instances, you'll be duplicating much of the same logic you say you've used previously in displaying a `UIAlertView`.

**Option 1:** Have the view with buttons that should only be displayed once as the first view.  In the `viewDidLoad` method, check whether the app has been launched before and a button has been selected.  If a button has been selected before, just go ahead and perform the segue straight from the `viewDidLoad` into the rest of the app.

**Option 2:** This time, instead of starting with the 1-time view, start with the standard first view.  Check if the app has been launched before or not, and if it has, perform a modal segue into the view where they select a button (otherwise just don't perform the segue).

---

I'm certain there's a more elegant solution to get this work in a better way, but this is a pretty simple implementation that should be quite easy to get working.

Answer (score 0):

I would us an NSUserDefault here. First check for the presence of a preference for the key you specify. If it doesn't exist you'll want to show the region selection view. If it does exist just use the region stored in the preference.

This way, if the preference every gets deleted or lost, the logic will be small enough that the user can recover fairly quickly.